# Mac OS X: Extending a shared library by adding a function

Tags: c, macos, shared, extend

I would like to extend a shared c library (dylib) on Mac OS X by adding a function. Let's call the function `const char *get_string(void)`. Here is my approach:

I created a new shared library containing the `get_string(void)` function and liked it against the library I wanted to extend. A library wrapper so to speak. So far so good. The next step would be to link an application against my new extended library but the problem is that the extended library does only export the symbol `_get_string` but not those symbols of the original library. That's why linking against the "extended" library (instead of the original library) produces a lot of unresolved symbol warnings/error.

Is there any way to export all those symbols of the original library (there are a lot) or is there a better approach to solve the problem. Basically I just want to extend an existing library. BTW I have access to the original library's source but I can't just recompile it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this option to ld:

```
     -reexport-lx
             This is the same as the -lx but specifies that the all symbols in library x should
             be available to clients linking to the library being created.  This was previously
             done with a separate -sub_library option.
```

Comment: Tanks, sounds good, but it does not work for me. I use Xcode and set the property "Other Linker Flags" to "-L/usr/local/lib -reexport-lparent" where libparent.dylib should be extended. It seems that libtool is not passing on the reexport flag. The parent library is not even linked against. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The sub_library flag is recognized but nm still does not list the symbols of the parent library

Comment: sorry, I avoid xcode like the plague. It's command-lines for me.